# Python subprocess command output badly formatted with any progress bar

Tags: python

I am calling a bash command from python with the following code.

```
with Popen(command.split(), stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='') # process line here

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

It prints out fine with anything that is on a single line, however when  it reaches any `progress bar` it starts print the lines diagonally across the screen.

The output looks something like this

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 295 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
language-pack-en* language-pack-en-base*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 295 not upgraded.
                                                                After this operation, 3967 kB disk space will be freed.
                                                                                                                       (Reading database ...
                                                                                                                                             (Reading database ... 5%
                                                                                                                                                                     (Reading database ... 10%
                  (Reading database ... 15%
                                           (Reading database ... 20%
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: It seems the printed string is longer than the screen width. This causes the line to be partially printed on the next one and then messes with align..

Comment: @Jib but that is only because it is printing a line that is supposed to update, i.e., `Loading 10%` becomes `Loading 10%      Loading 11%`  instead of just `Loading 11%`

Comment: The line probably ends with a carriage return, but `universal_newlines` is causing it to be treated as a linefeed.

Comment: @chepner what do I do to correct this?

Comment: I would probably stop trying to intercept the output and just let the subprocess inherit its standard output from your script.

Comment: You may want to use \r to go back to the start of the line so that it gets overwritten

Comment: At _minimum_ turn off `universal_newlines`, but I'm strongly in agreement with chepner here -- just stop intercepting stdout if you don't have an _extremely_ compelling reason to do so.